# How can I directly print from web application(using Spring and angular 2) to local printer?

Tags: spring, angular, google-cloud-print

I want to integrate google cloud printer(may be different tech) to print anything from web application to local printer directly.

Thanks.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I dont know how to start with.Do I have to do it in frontend(Angular 2)or Backend(Spring)?

Comment: Backend for sure

Comment: did u get any solution?